# Is this game with a spinner fair?

Tags: probability, game-theory

Matt and Hannah are playing a game with a spinner. The options on the spinner are $1/8$, $1/4$, $2/5$, and $1/3$.  They spin twice and add the fractions. If the sum is greater than $1/2$, Hannah gets a point.  If the sum is less then $1/2$, Matt gets a point. If the sum is $1/2$, then no one gets a point. 
Is the game fair? If so, why? or why not?

I was thinking you would need to find out all the combinations of the spinner, but that would take too much. I'm stumped!

Comment: And the task is...? Also sharing your thoughts helps us give the best answers.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the question

Comment: Since they spin twice, there are only $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ possible sequences of outcomes, not all of which are distinct.

Comment: So who would have the advantage?

Comment: Just make a little 4x4 addition table. Count how many of the 16 entries are larger than 1/2, and how many are smaller than 1/2. If there are more of the former, Hannah has the advantage, and if there are more of the latter Matt has the advantage.

Comment: On this site, it is expected that you show us what you have attempted and indicate where you are stuck.  People will be much more receptive to answering your question after you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have $16$ combinations, To get this answer, I wrote down all the possible combinations on a bit of paper, so not too difficult, I'm sure you just didn't know where to start.

I am now making the assumption that all have equal probability of landing on each one 25% each.

I simply added up all the combinations and here are my findings.

$$1/8+1/8=0.250$$
$$1/8+1/4=0.375$$
$$1/8+2/5=0.525$$
$$1/8+1/3=0.458$$
$$1/4+1/4=0.500$$
$$1/4+2/5=0.650$$
$$1/4+1/3=0.583$$
$$2/5+2/5=0.800$$
$$2/5+1/3=0.733$$
$$1/3+1/3=0.666$$
$$1/4+1/8=0.375$$
$$2/5+1/4=0.650$$
$$2/5+1/8=0.525$$
$$1/3+2/5=0.733$$
$$1/3+1/4=0.583$$
$$1/3+1/8=0.458$$

Based on this, one must have more of an advantage because you only have $1$ possibility of a draw, If Hannah $2/5$ at any point, she will win and Matt will lose.

So, who wins, just get the percentage. So the odds of it being $50\%<$ is $62.5\%$ as $10$ are wins and $5$ losses. This would mean that Hannah would win $62.5\%$ of all games so the game is unfair.

There is a $6.25\%$ of a draw, and a $31.25\%$ of Matt winning.

Hopefully this answered your question.

Comment: There are only $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ possible sequences.  How did you get $20$?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, there are 16, I just made a typo, all fixed now :)

Comment: Yes, sorry if i made it a little bit confusing, I mean that $1/8$ $1/4$ $1/3$ and $2/5$ all have equal probability. It would have helped if you mentioned this initially, but once I added them all together and got greater than one I realised that you wanted them all to have equal probability. Those were the combinations you would be able to get. I put them there so people wouldn't have to work it out and realise that Hannah will have a greater chance of winning

Comment: Your assumptions are that the four outcomes on the spinner are equally likely to occur and that the results of the spins are independent.  Also, if you check your calculations, Hannah wins $10$ of the $16$ possible outcomes, Matt wins $5$, and one results in a tie, so the probability that she wins is $0.625$ rather than $0.6875$.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm correct, $68.75\%$ chance of Hannah winning, $6.25\%$ of a draw and $25\%$ of Matt winning. It all adds up to $100\%$

Comment: Wait, I wrote down on my paper that the last one was higher than lower, silly me

Comment: You could also work out the expected value of one spin, assuming the spinner is fair if you just want to know if the game is fair (not the specific likelihoods of either player winning).

Comment: In the third to last paragraph, you mean that the probability that the sum exceeds $1/2$ is $0.625$, so $10$ are wins for Hannah and $5$ are losses.

Comment: Well, of one spin, they all have an equal chance. So that would mean you would always get less than half. An average of what you would get would be $0.2770833333$. After 2 spins the average is $0.55385$

Comment: I would recommend lowering 2/5 to maybe 3/7, you want it to get to a perfect 50 for it to be fair.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Changed it now, I had misread 0.4583 and thought it was higher, so that was the initial post. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: no, it's not fair. It is easy to see that there are $16$ possible results when you spin it twice, and exactly one of these ($1/4,1/4$) is a draw. It's impossible for Hannah to win exactly half of the remaining $15$ possibilities, since $15$ is odd.